# JMS integration tests with Maven and Glassfish

Tags: maven, glassfish, integration-testing

I'm developing an app requiring MDB, running over Glassfish 3.1. I've managed already to run unit/integration tests of simple EJBs using embedded container with no problem. Now I'm trying to create integration tests for my MDBs.

1) I tried launching the Glassfish embedded server programatically, but it does not support creation of JMS queues.

2) I run a Glassfish server from the Maven plugin.
Now I can create queues, and deploy my MDBs, no problem at all. Now, I just can't figure out a way of running JUnit.
- When I create an InitialContext, it times-out when accessing the local server. I have no ways of accessing my beans.

I found a workaround, but it's not serving my needs perfectly:
In my test sources, I created a simple Singleton @Startup bean. In the @PostConstruct method, I call the unit test classes I want to achieve. In order for this bean to be deployed, I have a special special maven build rule that packages some of my tests files in the EJB jar. Deploying this special jar results in my tests being launch. To make it clear, here's an extract of my Maven file:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-ejb</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*TestTrigger.class</include>
                                    <include>**/*IntegrationTest.class</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>ejb</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>TEST</classifier>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-ejb</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <goalPrefix>glassfish</goalPrefix>
                <app>target/${project.build.finalName}-TEST.jar</app>
                <port>8080</port>
                <name>MyApp</name>
                <serverID>embedded</serverID>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>admin</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>admin</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <commands>
                            <param>create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory jms/TestQueueConnectionFactory</param>
                            <param>create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.Queue --property imqDestinationName=ceQueue jms/ceQueue</param>
                        </commands>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>undeploy</goal>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.8.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Now, is there any way my IntegrationTest can be launched using surfire, in order to produce a proper report and fail build if test don't pass? Not to mention Cobertura.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't solve my problem so to say. What I had to do is upgrade to GlassFish 3.1.1. This version supports JMS in embedded mode. Therefore I can run a server programatically and deploy the queues I want using the admin command runner.

I just lost a bit of time trying to name my connection factory **jms/connectionFactory** where the **jms/** prefix was unnecessary and was failing all lookups.

I also had to include a thread sleep in all my unit tests or else the server would close before tests are over.